# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, npm-scripts, vite

I have an error when running vue.js 3  with vite

[image: 1]

I added nodejs into Variable Environments before

I have tried these things but not working

- using `npm cache clear` & `npm cache clear --force` but still error and receive `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`
- deleted node_modules folder and package.lock.json and run `npm install`
- re-clone my repo on Github
- re-installed Nodejs, VSCode, vite.js, update to latest npm

Debug log:

````
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'dev'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.2
2 info using node@v17.1.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xfago-cms-vue\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Admin\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 12ms
27 timing command:run-script Completed in 7ms
28 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')
28 verbose stack     at promiseSpawnUid (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:70:18)
28 verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:15:10)
28 verbose stack     at runScriptPkg (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\run-script-pkg.js:54:13)
28 verbose stack     at runScript (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\run-script.js:9:16)
28 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:129:13)
29 verbose cwd C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\xfago-cms-vue
30 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
31 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
32 verbose node v17.1.0
33 verbose npm  v8.1.2
34 error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')
35 verbose exit 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run the command npm init to create a "complete" package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

same issue found to me beacuse i used

```
npm config --global set x = "Y"
```

so this is the huge mistake i did for that i need to unintall nodejs
and also delete **C:/Users/"username"/Appdata/Roming/** delete npm from here as well,
again install it, it worked for me
i know this is not a solution but issue is according to me have only this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that error occurred when I tried to deploy a project to gh-pages with a custom message.
But it worked with a default one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Run the same code in windows powershell if you are using Windows.
I was facing the same issue while running npm start on git bash.
Running npm start on Powershell resolved the issue for me.